# Multiplying a letter by a number

Tags: javascript

Trying to get around some JavaScript code I am looking at. I am seeing things like this:

```
var myVariable = "X";
var result = myVariable * 6;
```

Coming from a C# background, this is new to me. Could somebody give me a quick primer on what is going on here? I am guessing that **result** would be equal to that letters position in the alphabet multiplied by 6, would I be correct?

Comment: Try it out and see what the result is!

Comment: Hit F12 , type "x"*6, see the result NaN. Developer console is an ultimately handy tool.

Comment: @fastreload or node. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am guessing that result would be equal to that letters position in the alphabet multiplied by 6, would I be correct?

No. JS is weakly typed, and values are implicitly typecasted to match the operator (a [multiplicative one](http://es5.github.com/#x11.5) here). In this case, the string `"X"` would be [converted to a number](http://es5.github.com/#x9.3) - leading to `NaN` as it's no valid numberic literal. The `result` would then be `NaN` as well.

To get the position in the alphabet, you'd use [`parseInt` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) with a non-decimal base (`parseInt("X", 36)-10`) or the [`charCodeAt` string method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt) (`"X".charCodeAt(0)-65`).

Comment: @Derek: It's ASCII codes. For lowercase letters, you'd need to subtract 97.

Answer (score 2):

The result would be `NaN` because "X" is not a number; multiplying a string with a number will always return `NaN`.

More information: [http://es5.github.com/](http://es5.github.com/#x11.5.1)

> The * operator performs multiplication, producing the product of its operands. Multiplication is commutative. Multiplication is not always associative in ECMAScript, because of finite precision.
>
> The result of a floating-point multiplication is governed by the rules of IEEE 754 binary double-precision arithmetic:
>
> - **If either operand is NaN, the result is NaN.**

---

If you want to get the letter's position in the English alphabet, try [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt):

```
myVariable.toUpperCase().charCodeAt(0) - 65;
```

Comment: `NaN` means Not a number for those who don't know.

Comment: `Array(16).join(6*'X')+' Batman!'` is the batman song for those who don't know.

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest solution to have a string `s` repeated `n` times is:

```
Array(n+1).join(s)
```

Reading your question again: To multiply the charcode of the first letter of `s` by `n`:

```
s.charCodeAt(0) * n
```

To get the character that corresponds to that multiplied charcode:

```
String.fromCharCode(s.charCodeAt(0) * n)
```

Comment: Yes, it would be, but that's completely unrelated to the question?

Comment: @Bergi updated, do you think I answered OP's question better, now?

Comment: Yep, that's better (though "charcode" is not exactly equivalent to "position in the alphabet")